# How to check a checkbox on focus of Input text in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to check a checkbox in table DOM on focus of input text, but am not able to access the checkbox element, but my focus is working

and here is my jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/9qha9vft/

here is my code

**Jquery code**

```
$("td .focus-evt").focus(function() {

$(this).siblings("td input.flat").prop('checked', true);;

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input and checkbox aren't siblings, they are in different TD's.

Go to the closest TR, then find the TD and checkbox

```
$("td .focus-evt").focus(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find("td input.flat").prop('checked', true);;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9qha9vft/1/)