# Automatically tick checkbox when clicking on another form input field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, checkbox

I'm trying to have a checkbox next to a form text-input field. The checkbox can be ticked on/off normally, however when clicking on the text-input field, the checkbox should be automatically ticked as well.

I tried this with putting the text-input inside the label for the checkbox, but it doesn't work. It works fine when I use normal text instead of the input-field:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="box">
<label for="box">
  <input type="text">
</label>
```

How can I achieve this with HTML/JS? I'm working in the context of a VueJS plugin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check a checkbox on focus of Input text in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358888/how-to-check-a-checkbox-on-focus-of-input-text-in-table)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a checkbox with a clickable label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293588/how-to-create-a-checkbox-with-a-clickable-label)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click action of `<input>` (focus & start editing) overrides `<label>`'s, so you'll have to use JS:

```js
document.querySelector('#text').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  document.querySelector('#box').checked=true
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="box">
<input type="text" id="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery to achieve this:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="box">
<label for="box"></label>
<input type="text" id="mytextinput">
```

JQuery:

```
$('#mytextinput').focus(function(){
$('#box').prop( "checked", true ); // true checks the checkbox false unchecks.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a listener to the text input that checks the box.

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector('#box');
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

input.addEventListener('click', () => {
  checkbox.checked = true;
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="box">
<label for="box">
  <input type="text">
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by setting an `onclick` attribute on text field like:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="box">
<label for="box">
  <input type="text" onclick="box.checked = true">
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    document.querySelector("#box").addEventListener('click',function(){
        document.querySelector("#checkbox").checked = true;
    });
```

```html
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
        <input type="text" id="box">
    </div>
```

Comment: @FZs Brother I haven't seen your solution. Actually when I was starting there was not a single answers here

Comment: No problem... Just mentioned

Answer (score 0):

just write it like this (worked for me):

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="box">Feeling lucky
</label>
```